# How To Customise My Hovering Navigation Bar Tabs

Tags: html, css

The tabs menu in my hovering navigation bar isn't level. The background area abrounf the tabs text is considerably wider than the rest of the navigation bar. And even the text in the dropdown menus have large gaps between words. I have tried to resolve this issue but I'm not very skilled at HTML. I have included the entire html coding for the navigation bar below:

```
#wctopdropcont{ /* width of the main bar categories */
width:100%;
height:40px;
display:block;
padding: 5.5px 0 0 0;
margin-left: 0;

z-index:100;
top:0px;
left:0px;
position:fixed;

background:#f8f8f8; 
opacity: 0.9;
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  }

#wctopdropnav{ /* social */
float: left;
width:97%;
height:7px;
display:block;
padding:0;
margin-left:30px; 
}
#wctopdropnav ul{
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;

} 
#wctopdropnav li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
line-height:35px;
margin:0;
padding:6.5px;/* height of the clicked bar */
background:#f8f8f8; 
}

#wctopdropnav li a, #wctopdropnav li a:link{
color:#000000;
float: left;
display:block;
margin: 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 9.5px!important;
font-family: karla, arial!important;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: normal!important;
letter-spacing : 0.09em;
}
#wctopdropnav li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li a:active,    #wctopdropnav .current_page_item a  {
color:black;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 5px;
background: #f8f8f8; /* Old browsers */
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
filter:black;  
}
#wctopdropnav li li a, #wctopdropnav li li a:link, #wctopdropnav li li a:visited{
font-size: 10px;
background:#f8f8f8;
color: #000000;
width: 95px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 1px;
line-height: 20px;
position: relative; 
}
#wctopdropnav li li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li li a:active {
color: black;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
filter: #f8f8f8;
}

#wctopdropnav li ul{
 z-index:9999;
position:absolute;
left:-999em;
height:auto;
width:170px;
margin:22px 0 0 0;
padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}

#wctopdropnav li:hover ul, #wctopdropnav li li:hover ul, #wctopdropnav li li li:hover ul, #wctopdropnav li.sfhover ul, #topwctopdropnav li li.sfhover ul, #topwctopdropnav li li li.sfhover ul{
left:auto
}

#wctopdropnav li:hover, #wctopdropnav li.sfhover{
 position:static
 }
```

The URL to my blog is as follows: http://www.blankesque.com  The problem is very visible.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The padding around your navigation is coming form the large `line-height` here:

```
#wctopdropnav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 35px; /* <--- HERE */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6.5px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
```

The vertical spacing of your drop down links is being effected by the `line-height` here:

```
#wctopdropnav li li a,
#wctopdropnav li li a:link,
#wctopdropnav li li a:visited {
    font-size: 10px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: #000000;
    width: 95px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1px;
    line-height: 20px;  /* <--- HERE */
    position: relative;
}
```

Reduce the value or remove these properties.